# Mysql Extract tables in hierachical json

Tags: mysql, json, nosql

I am trying to extract multiples tables from a Mysql Database.
The tables schema looks like that.
First Tables.

```
{
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
                "dst_apid": {
                        "type": "number"
                },
                "src_apid": {
                        "type":"number"
                }}
```

Second Tables

```
{
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
                "apid": {
                        "type": "number"
                },
                "city": {
                        "type":"number"
                }}
```

But I would like to have an extracted files like this.

```
{
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                        "dst_apid": {
                                "type": "number",
                                "properties":{
                                        "city": {
                                                "type":"number"
}}
```

Should I use an OUTER join on the full tables? I know i can't extract directly a json from mysql but maybe if I can extract a proper CSV I could easily parse it.

Comment: Could you set up a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: mysql 5.7 supports [json data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) and supports [json functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html).